# setting hiddenfield value from javascript but not getting it in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Im setting value of hiddenfield by onclientclick event of save button which calls javascript function and successfuly sets the value and after that it  postback but in codebehind hiddenfield value is empty

here is code

```
 function SetTotal() {
        hdfTotal.Value = $('#spTotal').text();

    }


<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfTotal" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaveUpdate" CssClass="blue btn" Text=" Save "  OnClientClick="SetTotal()" OnClick="btnSaveUpdate_Click" />
```

Comment: you need to sure that, SetTotal() function must run before postback.

Comment: Are you sure in your server side code you are not re-setting `hdfTotal` value?

Comment: It is running before postback it is confirmed value is assigning to hdfTotal.Vakue

Comment: put a break point in your page_load and check where the hidden field's value is lost

Comment: also please post your button click code behind

Comment: Can you put 'Alert' in your js function and see if it pops before postback?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it should be like

```
 $('#hdfTotal').Val($('#spTotal').text());
```

Comment: yeah it works but i didnt understand the logic value is also assigning in my case .. where is the difference

Comment: Its the syntax. You should have used something like.  document.getElementById('hdfTotal').value to set that